# Can I fetch Transfers associated with a Stripe Payout?

Tags: stripe-payments

When I receive a payout created or paid webhook from Stripe, and I have the payout id, is there a way to fetch all the transfers that were created for that payout?

I can fetch the payout like this

```
var service = new PayoutService();
var payout = await service.GetAsync("po_1KJOuO***********h8S");
```

It looks like the payout has a "BalanceTransaction" property, but I'm not sure if it would contain "Transfers" as I don't see it in the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For transfers related to a specific Payout you can [specify the `type` attribute in your request to the Balance Transactions API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list) `/v1/balance_transactions`.  You can also [expand the `source` attribute on the Balance Transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-source) object to get the related payout object as well in a single request.

Below is an example of how you make this request in Python using the official Stripe library

```
transfers = stripe.BalanceTransaction.list(
  payout=payout.id,
  type="transfer",
  expand=["source"],
)
```