# I'm receiving a Stripe exception "No such payout: 'po_1KJ6pFQ**********YsFVzT4'" when fetching balance transactions

Tags: stripe-payments

I'd like to fetch all the Stripe Transfers that make up a Payout. I'm following this Stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70762527/can-i-fetch-transfers-associated-with-a-stripe-payout) that says fetch the balance transactions and pass in a payout ID and set the type to "transfer".

In my Stripe dashboard I can see multiple payouts and I'm just copying/pasting different ID's to test this call.

**Problem** - I keep getting the same error message from Stripe saying "No such payout: 'po_1KJ6pFQ**********YsFVzT4'"

Here's how I'm calling the balance transactions.

```
var options = new BalanceTransactionListOptions
{
     Payout = "po_1KJ6pFQ**********YsFVzT4",
     // Type = "transfer",
     // Limit = 100,
};
var service = new BalanceTransactionService();
try {
        StripeList<BalanceTransaction> balanceTransactions = service.List(options);
        foreach(BalanceTransaction balTransaction in balanceTransactions) { // do something }     
}
} catch(StripeException ex) {
    var e = ex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such (object) error messages occurs when the object you're attempting to access does not exist on the Stripe account.

By default, the request would be made on the Stripe account whose API key you're using. If you're using Connect and you need to access an object on a connected account, you should use your platform's API key and the [Stripe-Account header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication).

```
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.StripeAccount = "{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}";

var options = new BalanceTransactionListOptions
{
     Payout = "po_1KJ6pFQ**********YsFVzT4",
     // Type = "transfer",
     // Limit = 100,
};
var service = new BalanceTransactionService();
try {
        StripeList<BalanceTransaction> balanceTransactions = service.List(options, requestOptions);
        foreach(BalanceTransaction balTransaction in balanceTransactions) { // do something }     
}
} catch(StripeException ex) {
    var e = ex;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex. I just ran through a test using the requestOptions w/ the StripeAccount ID and it works, but the problem I have is I don't know the StripeAccount when I need to make this call. ex. I receive a Payout.Paid webhook. The webhook has the payout ID, now I need to track this payout back to all the Transfers. When I receive the webhook I have no way of knowing the connected account ID. Unless it's nested somewhere in the Payout object or I can extrapolate it from other data in the Payout object?

Comment: actually I think I can get it from the destination ID. That will take me to the Connected Account ID in my DB!

Comment: you can probably use the top-level account property which is included on each event for a connected account - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks#connect-webhooks